# Structure theorem for non-Noetherian local rings

Tags: reference-request, ac.commutative-algebra, local-rings, nonnoetherian

Is there a structure theorem (like *Cohen* 's structure theorem) for non-Noetherian local rings?

I am adding what I am looking for as someone asked in the comment.

If $R$ is a local domain (not necessarily complete) containing a field $k$ , then I am looking for something like that there exist $S=k[[x_1,x_2, \ldots, ..]]$  (infinitely many variables if  $R$ has infinite Krull dimension ) such that $ S \subset R$ and $R$ is finitely generated as a module over $S$?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more? What are you looking for? You can edit your question.

Comment: I have edited the post @AndrásBátkai thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.nmj/1118764705) is a paper by Nagata that provides an answer for rings satisfying Krull's intersection theorem.